# Linux on CB3-111 (Acer Chromebook)

Tags: boot, dual-boot, acer, chromebook

I've been trying to boot/dual boot my Chromebook into Linux and nothing works! I have seen so may different videos on it and followed so many different web tutorials, but nothing seems to work!

I have tried and successfully run Ubuntu and [Xfce](https://www.xfce.org/) through the Chromebook Terminal by following [these instructions](https://www.linux.com/learn/how-easily-install-ubuntu-chromebook-crouton). The problem is, that after a while it just stops working!

Is there some way for me to boot Linux on my computer separately from the ChromeOS whether it be Dual or just Linux, that has been proven to work on the Acer CB3-111-C8UB?

Answer (score 0):

Well I just found out why USB booting doesn't work and you can make it work but then it causes many limitations that are just a major annoyance.
[link to the website](https://samsclass.info/128/proj/chromebooks.htm)

1. You must open the case and remove a write-protect screw.
2. You must use a USB flash drive as the main storage device. The internal SSD will be useless.
3. You cannot boot to ChromeOS anymore.
4. You must use modified firmware designed for a different device, which has a chance of failing and rendering your Chromebook unbootable.
5. You cannot use Ubuntu 14.04 LTS, because the trackpad won't work. You must use the latest version, 15.04, which will only be supported for nine months, and keep updating to later versions frequently.

(List provided from website linked above)

Comment: Have you tried 16.04 ? it's supported for far longer. Also, alternative to usb would be to use larger internal ssd drive.

Comment: Hi! Note: right now, the latest LTS Ubuntu version is 16.04.

Comment: @Serg Have I tried 16.04 for which method?

Comment: @CristianaNicolae Yea I am well aware it is, I just copied and pasted the limitations that the website pointed out.

Comment: @Dilan - Yes, I noticed that, but I was wondering what the author of that article would have said regarding 16.04. Now, regarding the quote itself, please, do mention that it is a quote and/or format it accordingly. Otherwise, only those who visit the link will understand why you forgot to mention 16.04. :-)

Comment: @Dilan all of them ? Any of them ?  I mean, since 15.04 already has support for Chromebooks, it's definitely in 16.04, so the point about installing 15.04 on Chromebook is . . .somewhat pointless, if there's pretty much better and newer version of the OS.

Comment: @Serg I have not tried it through the Chromebook terminal so I'll be sure to give it a go